# how to rebase branch from git kraken

Tags: git, version-control, gitkraken

So I have a branch that was created from develop called feature/123

I have done some work on it, but in the meanwhile develop was worked on and now my branch is behind. I need to rebase but not sure how to in in git kraken.

in my merge request in gitlab i have this message

`Fast-forward merge is not possible. To merge this request, first rebase locally.`

So, in order to do this, do I have to:

check in develop, right click feature/123 and select 'Rebase develop onto feature/123'

or

check in feature/123, right click develop and select 'Rebase feature/123 into develop'

i remember the wording being confusing here, as well as which brach to be checked into at the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to rebase feature/123 onto develop.

When you're rebasing branch X onto branch Y, you're saying that branch Y is the base branch. And a rebase will essentially make it as if you've just checked out branch X freshly, as a new branch, from branch Y.